# having trouble with logic on crawling more than 1 page, only working for first and second page

Tags: java, web-crawler

I am crawling reddit by starting out at /r/pics. I search the html for the  for the next page. It works when I start in /r/pics, and then the following would be for example

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/?count=25&amp;after=t3_1tem9l
```

After I grab this url, I set this as my current url and scrape again, but it always keeps returning the same url..instead of the next. I feel I am missing something important but to me the code looks finished..

```
public void getNextPage() {
    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            System.out.println(url);
        Elements next = doc.getElementsByTag("span");
        for (Element n : next) {
            if (n.className().equals("nextprev")) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern
                        .compile("http://www.reddit.com/r/\\w+/\\?count=\\w+&amp;after=\\w+");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(n.toString());
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group());
                    url = matcher.group();
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        System.out.println(url);
    }


}
```

the url is an instance variable so it should change after I run getNextPage(). Here is main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scraper scraper = new Scraper();        
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 3) {
            i++;
            scraper.getNextPage();
        }

    }
```

here is the result

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/
http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/?count=25&amp;after=t3_1teq33
http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/?count=25&amp;after=t3_1teq33
```

the third url returned is just a repeat of the second one, it should be count=75. Been stuck for awhile before I decided to give up for now.

edit:

I think its because after the first clicking of next, there is now a "prev" and a "next". My regex is prob not picking up the url...need to figure out how to fix it

Comment: When you run the code in a debugger, where does the code not work as expected?

Comment: hm I am not getting any errors but I am just not getting the results I want. It must be inside my getNextPage method, and the regex I think..I didn't consider the regex failing

Comment: Judging by the `$amp;` in that URL, you have HTML-encoded input here. That probably isn't going to help matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsoup probably supports xpath. The xpath query you are looking for is :

```
//span[@class='nextprev']/a[2]/@href
```

Instead of relying on regular expressions, this might be easier.

If you are going the regex way, capture the `after` part of the regex. The highest count gives the url to the next page.

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/\\w+/\\?count=\\w+&amp;after=(\\w+)
```

The url with the largest `after` number gives the url to the next page.

Better still use any of the java wrappers around the reddit api.

Comment: thanks, I was just doing this to learn something new so I didn't want to completely abstract it.